# Диаграммы с помощью Google Charts, как изменить плавную линию графика на жесткую?

Tags: javascript, график, google-chart

Я сделал график помощью гугл-чарта, но как вы видите один график имеет изгибы не такие как все остальные.

Знает ли кто-нибудь как изменить график так, чтобы красная линия не была плавной? Нужно сделать красный именно такой, как синий и жёлтый - с грубыми изгибами.

Спасибо за вашу помощь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите код к вопросу, иначе все бессмысленно. На данный момент вариант ответа один: чтобы сделать красный как синий и желтый, надо его делать как синий и желтый.

Answer (score 1):

Без кода конкретный ответ дать невозможно.

[Вот](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) официальная документация по графикам google.

Исходя из того что есть, могу предположить что у вас в свойствах красной линии графика написано:

```
curveType: 'function'
```

замените на это (или пропишите, если нет):

```
curveType: 'none'
```